# Why does the reducer get more memory than the mapper?

Tags: hadoop, memory, hadoop-yarn, mapper, reducers

Why is it that in the Hadoop Yarn memory configuration the reducer always gets more memory than the mapper?

Example:

```
mapreduce.map.memory.mb = 7
mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb = 14
mapreduce.map.java.opts = 0.8 * 7 = 5,6
mapreduce.reduce.java.opts = 0.8 * 2 * 7 = 11,2
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to generalize recommendations for YARN MRv2 configurations vendors will give memory recommendations for common use cases they encounter and have been talked about in the community. That is the case in this recommendation just like any other.

**In short, Mappers filter and Reducers aggregate.**

But the reason that they make this recommendation is because in MapReduce data flow, we have a couple of phases: Map, Copy, Sort/Merge, Reduce. Mappers take data in partitioned chunks and then filter it using the Map method. This filter reduces the amount of data from the input.

Then this output is saved in HDFS and shared with Reducers via HTTP. This takes care of Map and Copy phases. So if you can imagine we have each mapper using the same memory requirements that the framework designated according to the MR Partitioner.

Now, during the Merge phase the reducers call this output from the copy stage and Merge it in stages. The merge is done in memory and the typical application  will benefit from increased memory. We have more control of Reducers in the MR framework since this option is configurable and we may want a single reduce output (in the case of a total sort) or simply less than the number of mappers that was determined for us by MR depending how the partitioning mechanism was set up. Either way we will receive (post shuffle) input that resembles the following: `(Key, List(Value))`. That list is what we aggregate over and another contributing reason for keeping the memory higher than the mapper.